# No database selected MySQL database connected to VS 2017 Community Edition (vb.net)

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I tried to search stack overflow and I found a post but the solution did not work for me.

I am using a MySql Database which is connected to Visual Studio 2017 Professional (Community Edition) software with the project being written in VB.net. I had to install the following extensions: - MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 and MySQL ConnectorNet 8.0.11. One should ensure that the DataSource is MySQL Database in order to connect to the MySQL database. I have managed to load/view the data, from the MySql database, into the DataGridView.  The source code is the following: -

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System
Public Class Form1

Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Port=3306; username=root; Password=mypassword")
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Private connStr As String
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
SubmitButton.Click

    Dim dtEmployee As New DataTable()

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeDate BETWEEN @d1 And @d2", connection)

    command.Parameters.Add("@d1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    command.Parameters.Add("@d2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

    adapter.Fill(dtEmployee)

    DataGridView.DataSource = dtEmployee

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView.DataSource = GetEmployeeList()

End Sub

Private Function GetEmployeeList() As DataTable

    Dim dtEmployee As New DataTable

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString

    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)

        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", conn)

            conn.Open()

            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            dtEmployee.Load(reader)

        End Using

    End Using

    Return dtEmployee

End Function
End Class
```

The code in the App.config file is: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="dbx" connectionString 
="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydatabase;user 
id=root;password=mypassword" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

I am now experiencing a problem as I am unable to filter the data between a specific data range in the Datagridview. When I set my date range between two dates and I click the submit button, a 'No database selected' error message is thrown at the line: -

```
adapter.Fill(dtLab)
```

and the error message: -

```
Exception Thrown
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'No database selected'
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
HResult=0x80004005
Message=No database selected
Source=MySql.Data
StackTrace:
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& 
insertedId)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& 
affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this one

Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Port=3306; database= mydatabase; username=root; Password=mypassword")

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I have one more question. Do you know the code to add a "Reset" button (i.e. to clear the filter of the data selected between two specific dates)? i also wanted to add an option group to show data in the DatagridView for: - (i) Today (ii) Tomorrow (iii)Yesterday (iv) Next 7 days and (v) Last 7 days. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try "DataGridView.Rows.Clear()" before you binding the new data.

Comment: Hi kyaw, Thank you for your help. I tried this code but it did not work: -          
     Private Sub reloadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
     System.EventArgs) _
            Handles reloadButton.Click

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

         End Sub

Comment: hi, I have the problem fixed now. The code that there was a GetEmployeeList Sub that gets *all* the Employees. That's what is needed to call from the ReloadButton & reset the bindingSource, like this:-                                                                 Private Sub ReloadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles reloadButton.Click

    Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = GetEmployeeList()
    ' You might have to reset the grid's DataSource, but maybe not, try it both ways
    Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1

End Sub